# Processing oscP5 Library

Tags: processing, osc

I'm using the oscP5 library in Processing.  I've already looked in the javadoc for oscP5 and I've browsed through the source but I can't figure it out.

When I get debug info like this:
**### new Client @ netP5.TcpClient@2515**

What does the value **2515** represent?  I know it is *not* the port the client is using.  Is it a unique id for the client?  Is it a variable I can access in the TcpClient class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the objects (TcpClient) address in memory. You find the source code at
src/netP5/AbstractTcpServer.java

```
TcpClient t = new TcpClient(this, _myServerSocket.accept(),
                           _myTcpPacketListener, _myPort, _myMode);
if (NetP5.DEBUG) {
  System.out.println("### new Client @ " + t);
}
```

This means, that your number is the String representation of TcpClient. Since nothing is implemented to return this - its the default behaviour: objects address. You can access this TcpClient object and its members as shown in to following example. I assume here for simpleness, that we look at the first object in the clients list.

```
if (oscP5tcpServer.tcpServer().getClients().length>0) {
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)oscP5tcpServer.tcpServer().getClient(0);
    print (tcpClient);                // address - same as your printed output
    print (tcpClient.netAddress());   // string with "ip:port"
    print (tcpClient.socket());       // Socket object 
  }
```

Please note, that most of the interesting information is contained in the base object AbstractTcpClient (as shown in the example).

Comment: I've already looked in TcpClient.java and can't find anything on where the number comes from. How would I access the process the id variable?

Comment: Ok I've looked deeper. Its not the thread ID but the objects (TcpClient) address. You can get information about the TcpClient. I'll change my answer accordingly.